# APIManagement "open console" button missing

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am following "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-cache#a-nametest-operation-acall-an-operation-and-test-the-caching" for Azure API Management.

I am unable to see the "Open Console" Button as referred.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the "Developer Portal" (make sure you are signed in)

Go to APIS, Open your API, there is a button called "Try it", which is the right button. The documentation needs to be updated.

In the new Azure Portal for API management (preview at the moment), you can also test the API's, there is a seperate "Test" tab available when you edit an API.